# How to display colored emojis in KDE Konsole?

Tags: konsole, emoji

GNOME terminal can correctly display colored emojis on my machine running Ubuntu 20.04.5.

But on **KDE Konsole**, I cannot get the emojis to be displayed. I have searched the internet to no avail.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [blog](https://christitus.com/emoji/) about it.

~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/01-emoji.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <!-- Use Google Emojis -->
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Segoe UI Emoji</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

or /etc/fonts/conf.d/02-emoji.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
  <fontconfig>

   <alias>
     <family>sans-serif</family>
     <prefer>
       <family>Your favorite sans-serif font name</family>
       <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
       <family>Noto Emoji</family>
     </prefer> 
   </alias>

   <alias>
     <family>serif</family>
     <prefer>
       <family>Your favorite serif font name</family>
       <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
       <family>Noto Emoji</family>
     </prefer>
   </alias>

   <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Your favorite monospace font name</family>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
      <family>Noto Emoji</family>
     </prefer>
   </alias>

  </fontconfig>
```

I ended up modifying only mono for my user (and I see the beautiful shell symbol or a bomb if command had non-zero exit code /see /):

```
 cat /home/avalon/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/01-emoji.conf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <!-- Use Google Emojis -->
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Segoe UI Emoji</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
  </match>

  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>IBM Plex Mono Text</family>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
      <family>Noto Emoji</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Usually you'd need to restart your application. And of course select the `monospace` family... actually I didn't do the latter, how it works is beyond me.

btw, to see that your config doesn't trow an error, you can run `fc-cache` in terminal. Otherwise things may not work without visible explanation.